# Excel automatic input triangle on a cell

Tags: vba, excel

Here's the code that I have and it works perfectly when I typed 0 it would create a diagonal line each cell I typed 0

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Variant
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim addr As String

    Set Target = Range("C10:AA36,C44:AA68")

    If Intersect(Target, ActiveCell) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each c In Target
        If c = 0 And Len(c) <> 0 Then
            addr = c.Address
            With Range(addr).Borders(xlDiagonalDown)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            End With
        ElseIf c > 0 And Len(c) > 0 Then
            addr = ActiveCell.Address
            With Range(addr).Borders(xlDiagonalDown)
                .LineStyle = xlNone
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I'm having a problem on adding an option for adding a shape of triangle for each cell I added when I type 1 right triangle then 2 for upside down triangle

Comment: What is the point of `Set Target = Range("C10:AA36,C44:AA68")`? It throws away the information regarding which cells changed.

Comment: Have you tested any of the answers you got below? any feedback ?

Answer (score 1):

I urge you to better understand the difference between a variant, a range, a cell and the value of that cell. If you do that you will write better code. For example, you declare `c As Variant`. But in reality you want c to be a cell which is a range. Then, with `If c = 0 And Len(c) <> 0` you address the default property of the range (which is the Value property), but you already forgot that it is a range. Because next you take the address of c and create a range from it. Obviously, two ranges with the same address must be the same range by two different names. I have sorted through your code and eliminated this an many other points of insufficient logic.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim LinStyl As Long
    Dim Arrow As Long
    Dim Col As Long

    Set Rng = Range("C10:AA36,C44:AA68")
    If Intersect(Rng, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Cell In Target
        If Len(Cell.Value) Then
            LinStyl = xlNone
            Arrow = 0
            Select Case Val(Cell.Value)
                Case 0
                    LinStyl = xlContinuous
                    Col = vbBlack
                Case 1
                    Arrow = 112
                    Col = vbGreen
                Case 2
                    Arrow = 113
                    Col = vbRed
            End Select
            With Cell
                If Arrow Then
                    .Font.Name = "Wingdings 3"
                Else
                    ' use the font specified for cell A1
                    .Font.Name = Cells(1, 1).Font.Name
                End If
                .Font.Color = Col
                .Value = Chr(Arrow)
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = LinStyl
            End With
        End If
    Next Cell
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Bear in mind that `Target` is the cell where the change occurred. If you paste data several cells can be changed at the same time. If the change occurred anywhere in `Range("C10:AA36,C44:AA68")` the changed cells will be treated, but not all of the cells in the range as your code had it.

Now the code works. It has a logic to it but it is far from perfect. Please take it from here and improve it further.

Answer (score 0):

A few comments/suggestions about your code:

- Since you are using the `Worksheet_Change` event. you can take full advantage of the `Target` object defined as `Range`, and is ~ to `ActiveCell`. So every where in your code you have `addr = c.Address` and `Range(addr)` can be replaced with `Target`.
- I've replaced your `If`s with `Select Case`, this way in the future you can add more shapes quite easily.

***Code***

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Rng1 As Range    
    Set Rng1 = Range("C10:AA36,C44:AA68")

    If Not Intersect(Target, Rng1) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Len(Target.Value) > 0 Then
            ' -- first clear the previous formatting --
            Target.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
            Target.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone

            Select Case Target.Value
                Case 0 ' create diagonal line
                    Target.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlContinuous

                Case 1 ' create right triangle
                    Target.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    Target.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    Target.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous

                Case 2 ' create up-side down  triangle
                    Target.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    Target.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    Target.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
            End Select
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```